# React - Type 'Component<P, S>' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifeCycle<P, S>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When I try and bundle my React application this is the error I am getting
[image]

This is what my @types/react/index.d.ts looks like:

```
class Component<P, S> implements ComponentLifecycle<P, S> {
    constructor(props?: P, context?: any);
    ...
}
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
class Component<P, S> {
    ...
}
```

I cannot remove my @types directory either since modules depend on it.
How would I need to change Component ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

FIXED -

Inside both react/index.d.ts files I just removed ComponentLifecycle everywhere it applies. So anything that extended / implemented it, i removed the extension / implementation. I also took out the ComponentLifecycle class. Now there are no errors and my app isn't broken